# Get var value as html from other file and append it using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one file named **my_list**.php. In `my_list.php`

```
<div class="inner">
 My Inner Content
</div>
```

I have another file called `utility.js`. In `utility.js`

```
var my_content = '<div class="outer">
                     <div class="inner-cover"></div>
                      Some content
                  </div>';
$(my_content).appendTo("body");
```

Now I want to load **my_list.php** inside `inner-cover` for that I wrote the following code

```
var my_content = '<div class="outer">
                     <div class="inner-cover"></div>
                      Some content
                  </div>'
$('.inner-cover').load('my_list.php');
$(my_content).appendTo("body");
```

But this code is not working. How can I include `my_list.php` inside `inner-cover`
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you just need to swap the code order

change

```
$('.inner-cover').load('my_list.php');
$(my_content).appendTo("body");
```

to

```
$(my_content).appendTo("body");
$('.inner-cover').load('my_list.php');
```

Because if we want to invoke `load()`,first we need to make sure the element exists

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice that. How can I assign my_list.php to  a variable and then append it using +

Comment: @Manik as I wrote,just swap the order and have a try